# how to pass column name of a table to the table valued function in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g

In a table I have comma separated values and I have to change these values into rows.

Ex: MSGVALUES column

145,24,56,78
  23,45,67

Expected output for this

```
MSGVALUES column
145
24
56
78
23
45
67
```

I got the above result by using table valued function(CSV) from Google search.

```
select * from table (CSV('10,20,'34',',')
```

If I execute CSV function then I am getting the result like

```
1
20
34
```

Now my actual requirement is I have to apply the above CSV function to my column name ie.MSG VALUE column. Assume my table name is CODEDESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you'd join the `table()` cast to your table like:

```
select csv.*
  from your_tab t, table(csv(t.msgvalues, ',')) csv;
```

Comment: hi i treid to vote for the above answer , it is giving -ve number the above answer is very useful to me